# Interpolation Between 2 4x4 Matrices

Tags: matrix, interpolation, quaternions

For skeletal animation using colladas, I need to linearly interpolate between 2 matrices. I saw somewhere that I can use quaternions to interpolate between matrices, but that only works for the rotational component, and I need to preserve the transform as well. Here is my code, which works, except for the translation part:

```cpp
float total = (orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame] - orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame - 1]) * 100.0;
float progress = orderedBones[i]->Animation->accumTime - orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame - 1] * 100.0;
float interpolation = progress / total;

glm::quat firstQuat = glm::quat_cast(orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1]);
glm::quat secondQuat = glm::quat_cast(orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame]);
glm::quat finalQuat = glm::slerp(firstQuat, secondQuat, interpolation);

orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(finalQuat);
```

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: I would suggest to add tag `quaternion` (singular)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux collada is a 3D file format that is capable of storing skeletal animation data. Its fairly irrelevant, but I thought I would mention it anyways.

Comment: What kind of matrices? For general matrices a linear interpolation would simply be (1-t)A+tB.

Comment: @user612313 They are 4x4 transformation matrices. I've solved the problem and posted and answer for future reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up solving my question through a bit more web surfing. For future reference, heres how to do it.

The transformation component is stored in a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
r r r t
r r r t
r r r t
0 0 0 1
```

where r is the rotational component and t is the translation component. Because of this, we can represent the translation component as a vector. 2 Vectors can be linearly interpolated, so we interpolate those two vectors and then shove them back into the rotation matrix when they're done. Heres the final code, but its a bit messy:

```cpp
float total = (orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame] - orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame - 1]) * ANIMATION_MULTIPLICATION_CONST;
float progress = orderedBones[i]->Animation->accumTime - orderedBones[i]->Animation->keyFrames[nextKeyFrame - 1] * ANIMATION_MULTIPLICATION_CONST;
float interpolation = progress / total;

glm::quat firstQuat = glm::quat_cast(orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1]);
glm::quat secondQuat = glm::quat_cast(orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame]);
glm::quat finalQuat = glm::slerp(firstQuat, secondQuat, interpolation);

orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix = glm::mat4_cast(finalQuat);

glm::vec4 transformComp1 = glm::vec4(
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1][0][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1][1][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1][2][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1][3][3]);
glm::vec4 transformComp2 = glm::vec4(
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame][0][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame][1][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame][2][3],
    orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame][3][3]);

glm::vec4 finalTrans = (float)(1.0 - interpolation) * transformComp1 + transformComp2 * interpolation;

// good for now, although in future the 2 transformation components need to be interpolated
orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix[0][3] = finalTrans.x;
orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix[1][3] = finalTrans.y;
orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix[2][3] = finalTrans.z;
orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix[3][3] = finalTrans.w;
```

Hope that answers anybody else's questions :)

Comment: In modern glm to access translation component use matrix[3], i.e in above code:
1) `glm::vec4 transformComp1 = orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame - 1][3]`
2) `glm::vec4 transformComp2 = orderedBones[i]->Animation->Matrices[nextKeyFrame][3]`
3) `orderedBones[i]->Animation->interpoltaedMatrix[3] = finalTrans`

Answer (score 2):

This function is working for me:

```
glm::mat4 interpolate(glm::mat4& _mat1, glm::mat4& _mat2, float _time)
{
    glm::quat rot0 = glm::quat_cast(_mat1);
    glm::quat rot1= glm::quat_cast(_mat2);

    glm::quat finalRot = glm::slerp(rot0, rot1, _time);

    glm::mat4 finalMat = glm::mat4_cast(finalRot);

    finalMat[3] = _mat1[3] * (1 - _time) + _mat2[3] * _time;
    
    return finalMat;
}
```

Comment: Does the scale part interpolate correctly?  glm has something similar https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00205.html#ga45099a92c5c704503565619ac2bcd5c6

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast matrix interpolation method if you are using an x86 architecture and enforce SIMD (#define GLM_FORCE_INTRINSICS), which will make GLM pack all matrices into compatible SIMD structures. It is using FMA instructions so any x86 CPU from 2013 and newer is compatible.

```
glm::mat4 interpolate(const glm::mat4& first, const glm::mat4& second,
                            const float coefficient) {
  glm::mat4 outMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  const float multiplier[4] = {coefficient, coefficient, coefficient,
                               coefficient};

  __m128 simdMultiplier = _mm_load_ps(multiplier);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    __m128 nPass = _mm_fnmadd_ps(simdMultiplier, first[i].data, first[i].data);
    __m128 outPass = _mm_fmadd_ps(simdMultiplier, second[i].data, nPass);

    outMatrix[i].data = outPass;
  }

  return outMatrix;
}
```